# Concatenation, Haskell

Tags: haskell, constructor, concatenation

Hi I am currently trying to concatenate two lists in Haskell similar to this:

l1 = [[aa,adb,adc], [aa,dd,gg]]
l2 = [[cc,abd,hh], [hh, cc, vvvv]]
result:
l3 = [[aa,adb,adc], [aa,dd,gg], [cc,abd,hh], [hh, cc, vvvv]]

here is my Haskell code:

Length-Ordered Lists over "character type" a (aka "strings over a")
Invariant: In LOL n xs, n == length xs
Note that automatically-derived Ord instance correctly orders LOLs

```
data LOL a = LOL Int [a] deriving (Eq,Ord)
instance Show a => Show (LOL a) where
show (LOL n xs) = show xs
```

-- Empty list (epsilon)

```
eps :: LOL a
eps = LOL 0 []
```

establish invariant

```
lol :: [a] -> LOL a
lol xs = LOL (length xs) xs
```

Normalized lists of LOLS
Lang a implies xs is ordered with no duplicates

```
type Lang a = [LOL a]
```

establish invariant

```
lang :: Ord a => [[a]] -> Lang a
lang xs = norm $ map lol xs
```

Here is where I am having a problem down below. I can't seem to connect the constructor Lang properly to establish a concatenation.

```
cat :: Ord a => Lang a -> Lang a -> Lang a
cat (ws) (zs)  = [ws:zs | ws++zs, ws <-Lang, zs <-Lang]
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: But you already concatenate it: `cat` is simply `cat = (++)` here.

Comment: I wish it was that simple. There is quite a few steps involved since I had to establish normalcy through the invariants described above. I attempted:cat [] a = [];
cat a [] = [];
cat (x:xs) (y:ys) = (xs++ys);but still to no avail. I recognize I have to use recursion to get my required output but... I can't figure out how to implement recursion to include both lists. (; although not syntactically correct - I used it to clarify endings)

Comment: LOL is used to both describe the length of the string and to hold the string aka: LOL 3 "lol". Lang is a list of these items.

Answer (score 1):

```
cat :: Ord a => Lang a -> Lang a -> Lang a
cat (ws) (zs)  = [ws:zs | ws++zs, ws <-Lang, zs <-Lang]
```

This has several syntactic and type errors.

- `[… | ws ++ zs, …]` tries to use `ws ++ zs` as a filter for the list comprehension, but `ws ++ zs` is of type `Lang a`, not `Bool`
- `[… | …, ws <- Lang, zs <- Lang]` *shadows* the parameters `ws` and `zs` with new local variables bound inside the comprehension; in addition, `Lang` is a type constructor, not a list, so you can’t iterate over it
- `ws : zs` assumes `ws` is an `a` and `zs` is a `[a]`, since the `(:)` operator prepends an element to a list, but you’re trying to work with `LOL a` values
- The `Ord` constraint is unnecessary, since you don’t use any comparison functions in the definition of `cat`

If you’re trying to concatenate *every* list (of type `LOL a`) from one `Lang` with every list from the other `Lang`, you need to do something like the following:

```
cat :: Lang a -> Lang a -> Lang a
cat ws zs = [catLol w z | w <- ws, z <- zs]

catLol :: LOL a -> LOL a -> LOL a
catLol (LOL m xs) (LOL n ys) = LOL (m + n) (xs ++ ys)
```

That is:

- `w :: LOL a` is bound to each element of `ws`
- Within that loop, `z :: LOL a` is bound to each element of `zs`
- The two `LOL a` values are concatenated using `catLol`
- `catLol` pattern matches on both its arguments to extract the length and list fields
- `catLol` returns a combined `LOL` with a length equal to the sum of the lengths of its operands, and items resulting from concatenating their list fields

This can of course be written without the `catLol` helper function:

```
cat :: Lang a -> Lang a -> Lang a
cat ws zs = [LOL (m + n) (xs ++ ys) | LOL m xs <- ws, LOL n ys <- zs]
```

But if you’re trying to just concatenate the two `Lang a` values, `cat` is equal to `(++)`, since they’re lists already:

```
-- Identical to: cat :: [LOL a] -> [LOL a] -> [LOL a]
cat :: Lang a -> Lang a -> Lang a
cat ws zs = ws ++ zs
```

If you want to normalise the result, then the `Ord` constraint makes sense to add back in, and you can just call your `norm` function, assuming it has type `(Ord a) => Lang a -> Lang a`:

```
cat :: (Ord a) => Lang a -> Lang a -> Lang a
cat ws zs = norm (ws ++ zs)
```